# I am getting a white empty page when opening this vue view (HTML)

Tags: javascript, java, html, vue.js

I am working on a simple ToDo List.
I have a problem: When opening the EditAssignee.vue in the browser I am getting an empty, white page. Only my header is displayed. Can anyone tell me, where the problem is? Is there something wrong with my router?
Be warned: I'm pretty new to this...
Thank you!

EditAssignee.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Edit Assignee</h1>
<!--    <h2>{{ this.assignee.prename }} {{ this.assignee.name }}</h2>-->
<!--    <p>{{ this.assignee.email }}</p>-->
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Prename" v-model="prename"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="name"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" v-model="email"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" v-on:click="updateAssignee">Save Changes</b-button>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import config from "@/config";

export default {
  name: "EditAssignee",
  data() {
    return {
      assignee: null,
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      prename: this.$route.params.prename,
      email: this.$route.params.email,
      name: this.$route.params.name,
      assignees: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getAssignee: function () {
      axios.get(`${config.apiBaseUrl}/assignees/${this.$route.params.id}`).then((response) => {
        // log response data to the browser console
        console.log(response.data);
        // assign response to data variable
        this.assignee = response.data;
      });
    },
    updateAssignee: function () {
      axios.put(`${config.apiBaseUrl}/assignees/${this.$route.params.id}`, {
        prename: this.prename,
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email
      })
          .then(response => {
            this.fetchAllAssignees();

            console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },

    created: function () {
      this.getAssignee()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Assignee.vue (Here's the button to the EditAssignee page)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Assignees</h1>

    <p>Please fill in all fields to create a new assignee. Please note that the assignee needs an email with the domain
      <i>.uni-stuttgart.de.</i></p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Prename" v-model="prename"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="name"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" v-model="email"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b-button variant="primary" size="sm" v-on:click="createAssignee"
    >Create new Assignee
    </b-button>
    <br><br>

    <b-alert v-bind:show="assignees.length === 0" variant="warning">
      No assignee available on the server...
    </b-alert>


    <div class="assigneeBox" v-for="assignee in assignees" v-bind:key="assignee.id">
      <h3>{{ assignee.prename }} {{ assignee.name }}</h3>
      <p>E-Mail: {{ assignee.email }}, ID: {{ assignee.id }}</p>

      <div>
        <b-button
            size="sm"
            variant="outline-danger"
            v-on:click="deleteAssignee(assignee.id)"
        >
          <b-icon-trash></b-icon-trash>
          Delete
        </b-button>

        <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" :to="`/assignees/${assignee.id}`"><b-icon-pencil></b-icon-pencil>
          Details & Edit
        </b-button>

        <hr>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import configuration with API url; @ refers to the src directory
import config from "@/config";
// import library for HTTP requests
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Assignees",
  data() {
    return {
      assignees: [],
      prename: this.$route.params.prename,
      email: this.$route.params.email,
      name: this.$route.params.name,
      deleteMessage: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // send GET request to API to fetch all assignees
    fetchAllAssignees: function () {
      axios.get(`${config.apiBaseUrl}/assignees`).then((response) => {
        // log response data to the browser console
        console.log(response.data);
        // assign response to data variable
        this.assignees = response.data;
      });
    },
    deleteAssignee: function (id) {
      // send DELETE request to API to delete a specific assignee by ID
      axios.delete(`${config.apiBaseUrl}/assignees/${id}`).then(() => {
        // update view by removing deleted assignee
        this.assignees = this.assignees.filter((assignee) => assignee.id !== id);
        // show success message using BootstrapVue toast component
        this.showToastMessage(
            "Alert",
            `Successfully deleted assignee with ID ${id}!`,
            "success"
        );
      });
    },
    createAssignee() {
      axios.post(`${config.apiBaseUrl}/assignees`, {prename: this.prename, name: this.name, email: this.email})
          .then(response => {
            this.fetchAllAssignees()
            this.showToastMessage(
                "Created",
                `${this.prename} ${this.name} has been created`,
                "success"
            );
            console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
    showToastMessage(title, msg, variant) {
      this.$bvToast.toast(msg, {
        title: title,
        variant: variant,
        solid: true,
        toaster: "b-toaster-top-center",
        autoHideDelay: 4000,
        appendToast: true
      });
    }
  },
  // executed after the component has been started
  created: function () {
    this.fetchAllAssignees();
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.assigneesBox {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #42b983;
  float: left;
  min-width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.assigneesLogo {
  height: 200px;
}

.assigneeBox button {
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Errors:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'prename')"

found in

---> <EditAssignee> at src/views/EditAssignee.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1893
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1848
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3571
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4081
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4495
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4484
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4088
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8459
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3137
merged @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3322
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6022
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5969
updateChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6260
patchVnode @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6363
updateChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6237
patchVnode @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6363
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6526
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3963
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4081
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4495
run @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4570
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4326
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1989
flushCallbacks @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1915
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1942
nextTick @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1999
queueWatcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4418
update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4560
notify @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730
reactiveSetter @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:3003
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:3002
updateRoute @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2414
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2263
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2402
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2001
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2008
runQueue @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2012
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2397
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2001
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2005
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2384
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2162
iterator @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2362
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2004
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2008
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2008
runQueue @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2012
confirmTransition @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2392
transitionTo @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2260
push @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2715
push @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:3037
handler @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1139
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6961
28 weitere Frames anzeigen
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1897 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'prename')
    at Proxy.render (EditAssignee.vue?be9f:11:1)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3569:1)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4081:1)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4495:1)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4484:1)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4088:1)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8459:1)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3137:1)
    at merged (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3322:1)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6022:1)
```

Comment: Check whether error logs exist on the console.

Comment: Yes, there are several errors in the browser console... I posted them above

Answer (score 0):

`Assignee.vue`

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "EditAssignee",
  data() {
    return {
      assignee: null,
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      assignees: [],
      prename:undefined //Add this.
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't have errors anymore and edit assignee works, as long as I don't add this code:
<h2>{{ this.assignee.prename }} {{ this.assignee.name }}</h2>

It's in the fourth and fifth line of my EditAssignee.vue. I've updated the displayed Errors above. It says "Cannot read properties of null"
Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The error log means that you are trying to read an attribute on an null object. The assignee is obtained from the network. Before the network request occurs, the Vue starts to read attributes. In this case, the assignee is still null. Therefore, before accessing an object that may be null, check whether the object is null.
In addition, this is not required for {{}}.

```
<h2>{{ assignee?`${assignee.prename} ${assignee.name}`:'' }}</h2>
<p>{{ assignee?assignee.email:'' }}</p>
```